# How to get worksheet names as table names while getting data using Power Query from SqlServer

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Power Query to get data form SQLServer into Excel and I am able to get all the data from selected tables. However the worksheets are getting named as Sheet1, Sheet2....SheetN.

Is there an option to get Sheet names as table names that i selected in Power Query menu?

Answer (score 2):

This will require a VBA solution, like the one in post #3 in this [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/power-bi/976542-powerquery-naming-worksheet-tabs.html).

This works fine if 1 query/table at a time is added, as this sheet will be activated upon loading the data; not sure how it works with multiple queries/tables. Possibly you need to select the new sheets first before they will be actually renamed. You can give it a try and share your findings. I'm curious if it works fine if all new sheets are selected at once or if you need to select them 1 by 1.